# Flyway on DB2 zOS - migration fail on schema creation

Tags: db2, flyway, zos

I'm trying to use flyway on a DB2 / zOS instance and I get an error when trying to migrate or baseline.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Create Schema - is not supported in db2 on zOS
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.db2zos.DB2zosSchema.doCreate(DB2zosSchema.java:62)
```

This limitations is documented on Flyway [website](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/db2zos) but how to workaround it?

Actually the DB is in place and schema is yet created with the same name gave into config as first and only schema. ("flyway.schemas=MYSCHEMA")

Migration should only execute a bunch of insert.

Baseline should only create flyway metadata table (flyway.table)

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I have a similar issue.

Comment: No, sorry, still I didn't found time to understand the whole tool workflow, in case I'll find a solution I'll post it here for sure.

Comment: Great, thanks. Meanwhile I have been able to proceed by cloning and rebuilding Flyway with this somewhat hacky modification: https://github.com/tbsalling/flyway/commit/3b517d25a56d9fa4698e6bdf78ae193031f76211